# How to add Twilio rest API in pants build tool?

Tags: java, sms, twilio

My build automation tool is `pants`.
The API I'd like to call to Twilio is: [Add a phone number to a service](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/services/api/phone-numbers)

I cannot find the artifact on the internet.
All I have is this in my BUILD file:

```
java_library(name='lib',
  sources=rglobs('*.java'),
  dependencies=[
'3rdparty:com.twilio.sdk.twilio',
]
)
```

However, when I do `import com.twilio.rest.messaging.v1.service.PhoneNumber;`
it cannot resolve it, what's the `rest` or `messaging` or the correct dependency that I should import to resolve the dependency please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I figured it out.

It's due to my Twilio version, the one my team was using is `7.8.1`, after upgrading it to `7.17.0`, the problem was resolved.

There's no other lib or artifact that you'll need to import to resolve this issue, Twilio has only this one publicly available library.

Thanks!